# Confidence Interval for covariance

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, covariance

I am looking to calculate the confidence interval for the covariance between two series. Both are of the same length (there are n pairs X,Y) and there is no missing data. I calculate covariance without a problem, but I am also looking for the confidence interval for said covariance.

As I already have the confidence interval for the Pearson correlation at a given confidence level (let´s say 95%), is it statistically correct to say that the confidence interval with the same confidence level for the covariance obeys the following:

Lower limit correlation confidence interval * standard deviation(X) * standard deviation(Y) <= cov(X,Y) <= Upper limit correlation confidence interval * standard deviation(X) * standard deviation(Y)

If this is not correct, which approach/steps should I follow?

Comment: Are this time series, with autocorrelation? or independent observations? We need such "details" to be able to answer? Any other distributional assumption, or do you want nonparametric? ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it misses info to be answerable? and the OP hasn't been seen for ages ...